# find neo4j libraries for java api

Tags: java, neo4j

I want to use neo4j libraries to connect my java app with neo4j database and follow the tutorials from http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html. 
At the beginning I copied the sources code from https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.2.2/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4j.java and netbeans complains about missing libraries like:

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.io.fs.FileUtils;
```

I have searched libraries from http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|2|g%3A%22org.neo4j%22 site for example:

```
 org.neo4j.graphdb
```

But can not find anywhere. Where can I find libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `neo4j-kernel` artifact and all of its (transitive) dependencies, see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-kernel.

Comment: where can I find org.neo4j.io.fs.FileUtils?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at http://search.Maven.org and searched Neo4j?

Comment: Well, just pick the good version (http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.neo4j%22%20AND%20a%3A%22neo4j%22), add it to the classpath and it works.